# Select query with calculated field that uses subquery with multiple conditions

Tags: mysql, select, subquery, calculated-columns

Three Tables:

COST_SAVINGS:  COST_SAVINGS_ID, ONE_TIME_CREDIT, CREATION_DATE, INVOICE_ID (FK to Invoice table)

INVOICE: INVOICE_ID, INVOICE_CURRENCY_CODE

EXCHANGE_RATE:  CURRENCY_RATE, CURRENCY_DATE

I'm reporting on Cost Savings (the first table). The challenge is that each cost savings amount can be in a different currency so I need a field that shows the converted amount based on the currency from the invoice table and a matching month / year between the Exchange.Ex_Date and Cost_Savings.Create_Date.

I'm getting an error that states:

> single-row subquery returns more than one row

This is what I have so far:

```
SELECT 
COST_SAVINGS.COST_SAVINGS_ID, 
COST_SAVINGS.CLAIM_TYPE, 
COST_SAVINGS.COMMENTS, 
COST_SAVINGS.COST_SAVINGS_STATUS, 
COST_SAVINGS.CREATION_DATE, 
COST_SAVINGS.DESCRIPTION,
COST_SAVINGS.ONE_TIME_CREDIT AS CREDIT_IN_NATIVE_CURRENCY,
FINANCE_INVOICE.CURRENCY_CODE,
COST_SAVINGS.ONE_TIME_CREDIT * 
    (SELECT EXCHANGE_RATE.CURRENCY_RATE 
     FROM EXCHANGE_RATE 
     WHERE EXTRACT (MONTH FROM COST_SAVINGS.CREATION_DATE) = EXTRACT (MONTH FROM EXCHANGE_RATE.CURRENCY_DATE)
     AND EXTRACT (YEAR FROM COST_SAVINGS.CREATION_DATE) = EXTRACT (YEAR FROM EXCHANGE_RATE.CURRENCY_DATE)
     AND FINANCE_INVOICE.CURRENCY_CODE = EXCHANGE_RATE.CURRENCY_CODE) AS CREDIT_IN_USD

FROM COST_SAVINGS

LEFT JOIN FINANCE_INVOICE ON COST_SAVINGS.INVOICE_ID = FINANCE_INVOICE.INVOICE_ID
```

I feel like the issue may be with the third WHERE clause in my subquery (Trying to match the Currency codes). I'm not sure how resolve it though. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Try putting `LIMIT 1` in your subquery:

```
...RENCY_CODE = EXCHANGE_RATE.CURRENCY_CODE LIMIT 1) AS CREDIT_IN_USD
```

I believe your subquery is returning multiple rows. That doesn't work when you use a subquery in place of a column name in your `SELECT` clause.

If you don't want to use a subquery in place of a column name, try something like this.  You'll join to a subquery generated virtual table.

Here's the virtual table for exchange rates. It uses `GROUP BY` to make one row (or no rows per month/year/currency code.   If more than one row is in the raw table for any month/year/code, they get averaged with `AVG()`. You could also use `MAX()` or `MIN()`.

```
          SELECT AVG(CURRENCY_RATE) CURRENCY_RATE,
                 CURRENCY_CODE,
                 EXTRACT(MONTH FROM CURRENCY_DATE) MONTH,
                 EXTRACT(YEAR FROM CURRENCY_DATE) YEAR
            FROM EXCHANGE_RATE 
           GROUP BY CURRENCY_CODE, 
                 EXTRACT(MONTH FROM CURRENCY_DATE),
                 EXTRACT(YEAR FROM CURRENCY_DATE)
```

Try this and convince yourself it works.

Then build it into your overall query.

```
SELECT 
      COST_SAVINGS.COST_SAVINGS_ID, 
      COST_SAVINGS.whatever,   ...   
      FINANCE_INVOICE.CURRENCY_CODE,
      (COST_SAVINGS.ONE_TIME_CREDIT * RATE.CURRENCY_RATE) AS CREDIT_IN_USD
FROM COST_SAVINGS
LEFT JOIN FINANCE_INVOICE ON COST_SAVINGS.INVOICE_ID = FINANCE_INVOICE.INVOICE_ID
LEFT JOIN (SELECT AVG(CURRENCY_RATE) CURRENCY_RATE,
                 CURRENCY_CODE,
                 EXTRACT(MONTH FROM CURRENCY_DATE) MONTH,
                 EXTRACT(YEAR FROM CURRENCY_DATE) YEAR
            FROM EXCHANGE_RATE 
           GROUP BY CURRENCY_CODE, 
                 EXTRACT(MONTH FROM CURRENCY_DATE),
                 EXTRACT(YEAR FROM CURRENCY_DATE)
    ) RATE ON RATE.CURRENCY_CODE = FINANCE_INVOICE.CURRENCY_CODE
          AND RATE.YEAR  = EXTRACT(YEAR  FROM COST_SAVINGS.CREATION_DATE)
          AND RATE.MONTH = EXTRACT(MONTH FROM COST_SAVINGS.CREATION_DATE)
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I added LIMIT 1 per your recommendation and now I'm getting an error that says that I'm missing a parentheses.The query I'm writing is through a vendor's portal so the error messages aren't terribly helpful. I've seen it throw this one a few times for odd non parentheses related issues so I don't trust it necessarily. Is there another approach I could consider instead of using a subquery to calculate a field in my SELECT query? Thank you again!